# jMeter - invoking jmx operations

Tags: java, jmeter, jmx, jmeter-plugins

I want to use jMeter in order to monitor some Java components using the jmx-enabled capability. I have created a test plan and is possible to read jmx metrix within jMeter using JMXMon Samples Collector.

Any ideas how can I invoke jmx operations from jMeter? I would like to invoke a jmx operation which is resetting some values.

```
// this is an operation that shows up in the operations tab in jconsole.
@JmxOperation(description = "Reset number of tries")
public String resetNumberOfTries() {
    nrOfTries = 0;
    return "The total number of tries was reset!";
}
```

How can I call this method from jMeter? Is it any plugin available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to use :

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- Groovy as language as it's very easy to call JMX from it:

  - http://www.groovy-lang.org/jmx.html

To add groovy, download it, unzip the file and copy groovy-all-X.X.X.jar in embeddable folder to jmeter/lib folder.

The JMeter Plugin JMXMon plugin you mention in your comment does not allow you to call a method, only to collect an MBean attribute value.

Comment: But there is a JMX monitor plugin for jmeter and OP is specifically asking about that plugin: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/

Comment: Indeed, with JMXMon is not possible to call a JMX method. I will try Groovy.